# Is there a fast way to update one json column data with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, database, procedure, data-migration

There is a column in a table as

```
table: articles
rows:  id           type: int(11)
       json_data    type: json
       created_at   type: datetime
       updated_at   type: datetime
```

Now the `json_data` is

```
{
   "version":"1",
   "title":"A good product",
   "body":"Very good",
   "published_at":null
}
```

Want to update its data to new json schema format based on the current meta data:

```
{
   "version":"2",
   "items":[
      {
         "title":"A good product",
         "body":"Very good",
         "published_at":null
      }
   ]
}
```

How to do it if not use a programming language. Is it possible to do it by MySQL's procedure?

Comment: This may be performed in one query. None stored procedure or external processing needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE articles
SET json_data = JSON_OBJECT('version', 2, 
                            'items', JSON_ARRAY(JSON_REMOVE(json_data, '$.version')));
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9e0235560dd2e1900907bf6e501d98b)

---

> If run the update command twice, the data will become nested and break the format - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ac1e31df231efd7a7332d86f65c703b5). Do you know how to avoid it even run many times? – iooi

Add proper WHERE, check "$.version", update only those rows where this value is 1:

```sql
UPDATE articles
SET json_data = JSON_OBJECT('version', 2, 'items', JSON_ARRAY(JSON_REMOVE(json_data, '$.version')))
WHERE json_data->>"$.version" = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9d6d002da08f5a83232b35afd3b53445)

Comment: Very powerful. Thank you very much!

Comment: If run the update command twice, the data will become nested and break the format - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ac1e31df231efd7a7332d86f65c703b5). Do you know how to avoid it even run many times?

Comment: @iooi Add proper WHERE, check "$.version", update only those rows where this value is 1.